# Remove overlap entries from postgres arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I am trying to remove entries from an array field that are found in a query.

tablename.listfield::integer[] has a full list
I am trying to remove a list of values from that field, which are gathered within the update query.
the ARRAY_REMOVE method only accepts single values, and the intarray module which has `int[] - int[]` doesn't seem to be an option.

the `ARRAY[] && ARRAY[]` can boolean return if there is overlap, but that doesn't help me

basically what I need is a real working version of this concept, which I know does not work.

`UDPATE tablename SET listfield = ARRAY_REMOVE( listfield, ( select id from othertable ) )`

is it possible to get this done with maybe a tricky CTE setup or something?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say `intarray` doesn't seem to be an option, because it works just fine:

```
... SET listfield = listfield - ( SELECT array_agg(id) FROM othertable )
```

But if you want to do this without installing the extension, you can `UNNEST` the array and use the `EXCEPT` construct:

```
... SET listfield = ARRAY(SELECT UNNEST(listfield) EXCEPT SELECT id FROM othertable)
```

Comment: fantastic thanks! looks like that's working exactly right